# How to modify the display of multiple selected values in select input in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I built a Shinyapp that has a multiple select input. Everything works fine, but when I select multiple values,

[This is the ugly box I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWKfZ.png)

Is there a way to format the display of the selected values? Maybe just with ticks in the dropdown list with the options or something like that?

Comment: Formatting details like that will require defining a custom CSS file, which is a whole adventure to go on just to remove the box. Would switching from `selectInput` to `checkboxGroupInput` solve your problem?

Comment: Or have a look at the `pickerInput` from [`shinyWidgets`](http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the items in the select box using this css

[image]

```
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input > div {
        background: #d8544c;
        color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

Code for example app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
        
      .selectize-control.multi .selectize-input > div {
        background: #d8544c;
        color: #fdfdfd;
}

    "))
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("select1",
                        "Choices:",
                        choices = names(mtcars), multiple = TRUE)
        ),
    mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("out")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$out <- renderPrint({
      input$select1
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the display of the box? Not only the color but the way it shows the selected options?